# Terraform for loop in a for loop

Tags: azure, loops, for-loop, terraform, flatten

I have the following Azure AD service principal in my terraform module.

```
module "test_app" {
  source = "../../../../../my-adapplication/"
  app_owners     = ["riker@domain.com","picard@domain.com"]
  app_roles      = [
    {
      allowed_member_types = [
        "User"
      ]
      description = "Read access to Test app"
      display_name = "Test App Read"
      is_enabled   = true
      value        = "TestApp.Read"
      id           = random_uuid.test_app_read.result
    },
    {
      allowed_member_types = [
        "User"
      ]
      description = "Write access to Test app"
      display_name = "Test App Write"
      is_enabled   = true
      value        = "TestApp.Write"
      id           = random_uuid.test_app_write.result
    },
    {
      allowed_member_types = [
        "User"
      ]
      description = "Admin access to Test app"
      display_name = "Test App Admin"
      is_enabled   = true
      value        = "TestApp.Admin"
      id           = random_uuid.test_app_admin.result
    }
  ]

 


  app_role_assignments = [
    {
       app_role_id        = random_uuid.test_app_read.result #"TestApp.Read"
       principal_object_id = data.azuread_group.group_role_read.object_id 
    },
    {
       app_role_id        = random_uuid.test_app_write.result #"TestApp.Write"
       principal_object_id = data.azuread_group.group_role_write.object_id
    },
    {
       app_role_id        = random_uuid.test_app_admin.result #"TestApp.Admin"
       principal_object_id = data.azuread_group.group_role_write.object_id
    }
  ]
   

}

resource "random_uuid" "test_app_read" {
}

resource "random_uuid" "test_app_write" {
}

resource "random_uuid" "test_app_admin" {
}

data "azuread_group" "group_role_read" {
  display_name = "group-role-read"
}

data "azuread_group" "group2_role_read" {
  display_name = "group2-role-read"
}

data "azuread_group" "group_role_write" {
  display_name = "group-role-write"
}

data "azuread_group" "group_role_admin" {
  display_name = "group-role-admin"
}
```

The `my-adapplication` module file looks like this:

```
resource "azuread_application" "app" {
  ...
  ...
  dynamic "app_role" {
    for_each = var.app_roles
    content {
      id                   = app_role.value["id"]
      allowed_member_types = app_role.value["allowed_member_types"]
      description          = app_role.value["description"]
      display_name         = app_role.value["display_name"]
      enabled              = app_role.value["is_enabled"]
      value                = app_role.value["value"]
    }
  }
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "sp" {
  application_id               = azuread_application.app.application_id
}


resource "azuread_app_role_assignment" "role" {
  for_each            = { for a in var.app_role_assignments : a.app_role_id => a }
  app_role_id         = each.value["app_role_id"]
  principal_object_id = each.value["principal_object_id"]
  resource_object_id  = azuread_service_principal.sp.object_id


}
```

The issue I am having is related to the app_role_assignments. If I pass in only a single `principal_object_id` it works. However if I pass in multiple `principal_object_id`s it doesn't work. For example `TestApp.Read` below:

```
app_role_assignments = [
    {
       app_role_id        = random_uuid.test_app_read.result #"TestApp.Read"
       principal_object_id = [data.azuread_group.group_role_read.object_id,data.azuread_group.group2_role_read.object_id]
    },
    {
       app_role_id        = random_uuid.test_app_write.result #"TestApp.Write"
       principal_object_id = data.azuread_group.group_role_write.object_id
    },
    {
       app_role_id        = random_uuid.test_app_admin.result #"TestApp.Admin"
       principal_object_id = data.azuread_group.group_role_write.object_id
    }
  ]
```

The error received is:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on .terraform/modules/test_app/main.tf line 116, in resource "azuread_app_role_assignment" "role":
│  116:   principal_object_id = each.value["principal_object_id"]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value["principal_object_id"] is tuple with 2 elements
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "principal_object_id": string required.
╵
```

How do I get terraform to loop over this `principal_object_id` list? I guess I am after a loop inside a loop. Is there a better way of doing this than the way I am above?

Is it possible to do this using `for_each` so I don't have the problems with list order changing if i use `count`/`for`.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `principal_object_id` only accepts a String, so you would need a `azuread_app_role_assignment` for each mapping. You cannot specify a list of APIs by the provider (and probably also the API) specification.

Comment: Exactly. So the ask is how do i loop over the `principal_object_id` list so i pass them in one at a time?

Comment: I meant `ids` but wrote APIs for some reason. Anyway: https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/flatten#flattening-nested-structures-for-for_each

Comment: Thanks Matt. I have tried `flatten` but I think i am getting the syntax wrong. In my `resource "azuread_app_role_assignment"` block i have a `for_each` with `=>` but i don't know how to then introduce `flatten` or another `for` loop. Any assistance here would be appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you could edit your question to include what you tried already after referring to that documentation, and what error message (or other unexpected behavior) you saw when you tried to run it.

Comment: I have mentioned what I have tried - i.e. the for loop but I don't know how to then loop on `principal_object_id` if it has more than one value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to re-organize your `app_role_assignments` and then **flatten** it. If you want `principal_object_id` to have more then one value, it should always be a **list**, even for a single element:

```
app_role_assignments = [
    {
       app_role_id        = random_uuid.test_app_read.result #"TestApp.Read"
       principal_object_id = [data.azuread_group.group_role_read.object_id,data.azuread_group.group2_role_read.object_id]
    },
    {
       app_role_id        = random_uuid.test_app_write.result #"TestApp.Write"
       principal_object_id = [data.azuread_group.group_role_write.object_id]
    },
    {
       app_role_id        = random_uuid.test_app_admin.result #"TestApp.Admin"
       principal_object_id = [data.azuread_group.group_role_write.object_id]
    }
  ]
```

then you can flatten is as:

```
locals {
  app_role_assignments_flat = merge([
      for val in var.app_role_assignments: {
        for principal_object_id in val["principal_object_id"]: 
            "${val.app_role_id}-${principal_object_id}" => {
                app_role_id = val.app_role_id
                principal_object_id = principal_object_id
          }
      }
    ]...) # please do NOT remove the dots
}
```

then

```
resource "azuread_app_role_assignment" "role" {
  for_each            = local.app_role_assignments_flat
  app_role_id         = each.value["app_role_id"]
  principal_object_id = each.value["principal_object_id"]
  resource_object_id  = azuread_service_principal.sp.object_id
}
```